# write.csv results of each foreach iteration in R

Tags: r, foreach, write.table

I am using **foreach** to parallelize my job for an extremely large dataset. Below is the code:

```
d <-
  foreach(a=files, .packages = 'hdf5r', .combine = 'cbind') %:%
    foreach(b=files, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
      
      values <- "perform calculations"
    

  } 
d
```

The output I get is in the form of a matrix ... as a result of the 'cbind' combine function in the outer foreach. See attached photo.

However, what I would really like to do, is be able to save each iteration results in a standalone .csv or .txt file.

I have tried using a user-defined function that does that to replace 'cbind' but no luck. I have also put write.table(......) in the body of the code but it only captures the last iteration and I'm not sure if adding another for loop inside a nested foreach is good practice.

Is there a clever way of solving my dilemma?

Thank you.

Results:

[What I am getting from the script above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJrAy.png)

Desired:

[What I need to save in individual .csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEK3a.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following. Untested but I have used it before and it can work or, at least, give an idea on how to make it.

The inner most `foreach` must return a value, put `values` as its last instruction.

The file name is my choice, change at will.

```
d <- foreach(a=files, .packages = 'hdf5r', .combine = 'cbind') %dopar% {
  tmp <- foreach(b=files, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
    
    values <- "perform calculations"
    values
  } 
  fname <- paste("result", i, "csv", sep = ".")
  fname <- file.path("~/tmp", fname)
  write.csv(tmp, fname, row.names = FALSE)
  # return value to outer loop
  tmp
}
d
```

Note that without the last `tmp`, returned to the outer most loop, `d` will be `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What can I substitute for "i" in fname <- paste("result", i, "csv", ...)? Would that be "a" in my example? I cannot seem to get it to work with "a".

Comment: Please ignore this follow up question. I used i from i = icount() in the iterators library. It's worked now! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @PhilRugwiro Sorry, I only saw your post now. You are right, the `i` is a typo, I copy&pasted from memory... It should be `a`, I don't believe you need `icount` (though it should also do it).